Should I not use copula if there is no significant dependence?
I have two variables, and I would like to get the joint distribution of those. I want to use copulas for that. However, when I checked for the dependence between those, I found no significant dependence. The dependence I checked was asymptotic dependence, using the R package Vinecopula.
The p-value of the independence checking test is based on a normal distribution, and the AIC is calculated using mean squared error. Attached is the test statistic for asymptotic independence:

My understanding of copulas says that an independent copula should be used instead of a parametric copula, if there is no significant dependence between the variables. However, after checking AIC of independent copula and other parametric copulas, I found that AIC of parametric copula is lower than that of independent copula.
My question is: should I use the independent copula even if it has a higher AIC than other copulas if there is no significant dependence? Or should I go with any parametric copula that has the lowest AIC?

Above all, draw a picture.  In this instance, perhaps the most useful picture would be a scatterplot of the data.  It is likely to reveal more than any of the calculations you have described.

Based on your results, I would guess that the independence test did not capture the type of dependence found in the data, while the parametric copula did capture it. If so, I would use the parametric copula.

@whuber Yes, I believe a visual analysis could provide more insight, but in my case, I have thousands of regions where the copulas are fitted. So it wont be feasible.

@RichardHardy That is exactly what I suspect- the test may fail to capture a specific type of dependence. Are there other types of independent tests that I can consider? Also, is it possible that low AIC by parametric copula is due to overfitting (Chatgpt suggested)?

@lsr729, I suppose that is a separate issue. If you tried a ton of different models, selected the best one and then are comparing it to a benchmark, it will tend to appear to deliver a better fit (likelihood, AIC, etc.) for the same sample than it has in population.

Are the AIC values significantly different from each other? Do the copula dependence parameters exhibit low values? Additionally, fitting a one-parametric or two-parametric copula function to the data resulted in increased AIC and BIC. It is worth noting that a majority of copula functions are capable of accurately modeling independence between variables. In the end, not all the independent tests can handle all the dependency situations.

@Dr.Statistics I was using one-parametric copulas and yes, the AIC difference was significant for some of the regions. I decided to go with the parametric copula if it has a lower AIC than the independent copula (as the independence test may have missed some specific dependence).

After you fit a copula function to your data, do the copula dependency parameters reach the independency level for the corresponding copula? If so, you should go with the independent copula.
